# Does webGL contain push/popMatrix?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

Does webGL contain push/popMatrix? and if not, how would I go about recreating them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, WebGL is based off of OpenGL ES 2.0, so there is no built in matrix management or fixed function pipeline. The model view and projection matrices need to be completely managed in your own code and passed to shaders at draw time. You really don't need push and pop matrix if you are using a scene graph or some kind of other similar scene management system. All you really need is a good matrix and vector math library.

If you are still set on using push and pop matrix, you could simply use an array of matrices, and write functions like push and pop that simply save your current matrix into the array and push or pop the index down.

I would get the OpenGL ES 2.0 programming guide if you need more help with transitioning to WebGL. The book's website here: http://opengles-book.com/ contains a download link to some source code with demos for a variety of platforms and languages including WebGL. It also contains a decent math library if you need it.

Comment: Just curious why you said you really ont need push/pop if you have a scene graph? I have a scene graph (basically a tree of objects to render). I would like the transformations on the parent object to affect its children objects (e.g. The ubiquitous Wheel and bolts example).

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar It depends on how the scene graph is designed. Usually I need to compute the world matrix as part of the graph simulation so rendering involves simply loading the matrix at each node.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL/Animating_objects_with_WebGL#More_matrix_operations) and [there](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=239), there is no native support but you can easily build such a stack with an Array.