# WebGL - What is the alternative to pushing & popping matrices?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I read the following post about the push/pop approach when rendering is not really being required when working with a scene/graph "system" (reference link below).

I am just curious now, if no matrix push/pop is required, how does one render (and transform) a set of objects properly, like the ubiquitous example of a rotating Wheel & Bolts?

See reference: 
[Does webGL contain push/popMatrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231619/does-webgl-contain-push-popmatrix/11231721#comment37750479_11231721)

Answer (score 1):

All that pushing and popping achieves is a matrix stack. All a matrix stack achieves is storage and restoration of a previous active matrix. So it's a convenient way to manage a scene for the same reason that a call stack is a convenient way to run a program but it's far from required.

So e.g. you might just have the camera matrix, `M`, and for each object `i`, the object matrix `Oi`.

Then to calculate the equivalent of GL's old `MODELVIEW` for each object in turn that's just the composition of `M` and `Oi`. No need to store or restore anything from a stack. You know `M` and you know `Oi` and that's all you need to know.

EDIT: e.g. for argument's sake suppose you were writing [Battlezone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlezone_%281980_video_game%29). Then you'd have a bunch of objects on the play field. Each object would have a position and a rotation. One such object would be the player, to which the camera is mounted. You might draw the scene by (i) computing a view matrix from the player's position and rotation; then (ii) looping through every object on the play field, computing a model matrix from its position and rotation; and, for each, (iii) composing the two, posting the result to OpenGL and making such geometry calls as are necessary to draw the object.

No stack.

The same thing applies for any play field that's just a flat list of objects (aside: I'm ignoring broad phase model culling for simplicity).

Now suppose some objects are child objects, for whom position and orientation is defined only in terms of a parent object. In that case, whether you store it as one or not, you have a tree of objects.

One solution might be essentially identical to the Battlezone solution, whereby you iterate through every object in turn but now you do:

```
model matrix = identity
while(object is not root)
{
    compose model matrix with matrix for this object
    let object = parent object
}
```

So you're walking back up from child to root.

Still no stack.

Conversely, you could flip things around and just let the normal call stack be a stack implicitly:

```
draw object: object, parent matrix: parent matrix

    child matrix = composition of parent matrix and this object's matrix
    draw object

    for(children of object)
    {
         draw object: child, parent matrix: child matrix
    }
```

So there's a stack in there but it's the call stack.

Of course your tree doesn't have to be a formal tree data structure. In the Battlezone example you had an implicit tree where everything is a first-level child of the root. Similarly any other code structure could effect an implicit tree.

Comment: Thanks. So let me get this straight. I should have an object matrix (i call it "model matrix" in my code) for each object? Currently i only have a single instance of this object/model matrix (i re-use the same matrix per object, where i clear the matrix (set the identity) before i start using it per object).

Comment: The thing im primarily confused about, however, is how to transform on a parent object and affect all of its children objects. How can i do this without using push/pop?

Comment: What do you think pushing and popping achieves? If you had camera, parent object and child object matrices `C`, `P` and `O` then you'd compose together `C`, `P` and `O` as your model-view. Just at no point put them onto a stack and then there's no stack. Traverse whatever means you already have for knowing the relationship between models.

Comment: Im talking about from an alternative approach where no matrix pushing/popping takes place.

Comment: In that case everything I've typed so far exactly answers your question. This is what a stack is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type) — **just don't implement one** and you won't have one. Use whatever other structure you have in place to describe your scene — often some kind of tree but it may just be a flat array or series of arrays. The issue of storage is completely unrelated to 3d maths.

Comment: I know what a stack is. But if you say there is no need for a stack to perform transformations in a hierarchical manner, then i shall take your word for it. Unfortunately i'm a visual learner. Do you know of any links (online resources) that can help explain this?

Comment: I honestly don't understand what there is to explain, so no. Just listen to yourself describe the problem: "Multiply together the camera matrix, the parent object matrix and the child object matrix". Where's the requirement for a stack in that? It sounds like what you're asking about is scene graphs, disguised as a matrix stack question. I'll expound a little by editing my answer.